# Overriding backbone's parse function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to use Backbone with an API.

The default API response format is:

```
{
somemetadatas:xxx , 
results:yyy
}
```

Whether it's a fetch for a single model or a collection.

So as far as I know I can override the Backbone `parse` function with:

```
parse: function (response) {
    return response.results;
},
```

But I've seen in [the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse):

> **parse** `collection.parse(response)`
>
> **parse** is called by Backbone whenever
>   a collection's models are returned by the server, in fetch. The
>   function is passed the raw `response` object, and should return the
>   array of model attributes to be added to the collection. The default
>   implementation is a no-op, simply passing through the JSON response.
>   Override this if you need to work with a preexisting API, or better
>   namespace your responses. Note that afterwards, if your model class
>   already has a `parse` function, it will be run against each fetched
>   model.

So if I have a response for a collection fetch like that:

```
{
somemetadatas:xxx , 
results:[user1,user2]
}
```

The first `parse` function on the collection will extract `[user1,user2]`.

But the doc says:

> Note that afterwards, if your model class
>   already has a `parse` function, it will be run against each fetched
>   model.

So it will try to find `response.results;` on `user1` and `user2`

I need both parse functions on the model and collection because both model and collection datas will be under the result attribute.

But if i fetch on a collection, I don't want the model parse function to be used againt a single array element.

---

So is there a solution to this problem?

I think of a solution where my collection parse function will transform something like this:

```
{
somemetadatas:xxx , 
results:[user1,user2]
}
```

into something like this:

```
[ {results.user1} , {results.user2} ]
```

So that the model parse function will not fail on a collection fetch.
But it's a bit hacky... is there any elegant solution to this problem?

---

By the way, as my API will always produce results of this form, is it possible to override by default the `parse` function of all my models and collections? (Sorry i'm a JS noob...)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could test if the data you receive is wrapped by a `results` member and react accordingly. For example,

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function (data) {
        if (_.isObject(data.results)) {
            return data.results;
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
});
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9rCH3/

If you want to generalize this behavior, either derive all your model classes from this base class or modify Backbone's prototype to provide this function :

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.parse = function (data) {
    if (_.isObject(data.results)) {
        return data.results;
    } else {
        return data;
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9rCH3/1/

Comment: My custom `parse` is called, but has no effect - the values in the model are only the initial ID that was provided in the constructor... Any ideas?

Comment: If you're trying to do things to your model ids, you can't since version 1.1.0. http://backbonejs.org/#changelog If it's not that, you will have to post a question.

Answer (score 1):

**Parse also must be implemented in the Collection.**

```
var EgCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    parse: function (data) {
       if (_.isObject(data.results)) {
          return data.results;
       } else {
          return data;
       }
    }
});
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse