# Backbone + RESTful API

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I have an existing RESTful API wich can't be changed.
Now, i'm working on the webclient.

I would like to use a library like backbone.js (for the first time).

Here is the design of the existing API

1.) `GET /persons` - Returns the whole collection of persons

2.) `GET /persons?p1=a&p2=b` (e.g.) - Returns a subset of the complete collection which matches the criteria specified by the query parameters

3.) `GET /persons/[id]` - Returns a person by id

4.) `POST /persons` - modifies the collection (e.g. creates a new person) and returns the specific result

### Issues:

- The problem with #1 (and #2): The output format is like this: `{size: 1, persons: [{'id': 1, 'firstname': 'foo', 'lastname': 'bar'}]}`
- The problem with #2: how to map such a requst to backbone.js?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an API that doesn't follow backbone's exact structure, you usually end up overriding some combination of `fetch` `parse` and `sync` within backbone. Backbone was designed so that overriding these things would be easy, since it's a common need:

- http://japhr.blogspot.com/2011/10/overriding-url-and-fetch-in-backbonejs.html
- [Overriding backbone's parse function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938500/overriding-backbones-parse-function)
- [How to override Backbone.sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096549/how-to-override-backbone-sync)

Answer (score 3):

For #1, you would override `parse`. For example, in your Persons collection you would put the following method:

```
parse: function(response) {
    return response.persons;
}
```

You are basically instructing the collection which attribute the models can be found in ('persons' in our case).

For #2, (as previously mentioned) it looks like you'll need to update `sync`. Hunter provided a good link in his response that should be really helpful.